# Solving differential equation related to sales

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A company finds that the sales of a particular product are declining by $12\%$  per year. That is $$\frac{dS}{dt} =−0.12S$$ 
If current sales are $4000  \text{ units per year}$, find how long it will take for the sale to be half the current amount.

How do I start this problem?

Comment: I would like to bring up a small (but not trivial) issue with the problem statement. The 1st and 2nd lines are not actually consistent with each other. If the sales are decreasing continuously such that they have fallen by exactly $12$% within the 1st year, then the differential eq. representing the sale cannot be $\frac{dS}{dt} = -0.12S$. Instead, it will be $\frac{dS}{dt} = \ln 0.88S \approx -0.1278S$. On the other hand, if the differential eq. is assumed to be exactly $\frac{dS}{dt} = -0.12S$, then the company's sales would have fallen by something like $11.3$% rather than exactly $12$%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dS}{dt} = -0.12\cdot S(t) \\ \implies \frac{dS}{S(t)} = -0.12dt$$ The LHS should look familiar, as it is the derivative of $\ln(S(t))$ while the RHS is the derivative of an order one polynomial. Hence, if we anti-differentiate both sides we'll get $$\ln(S(t)) = -0.12t+C \\ \implies S(t) = e^{-0.12t+C} \\ = e^Ce^{-0.12t}$$ for some constant $C$. Lastly we know that the initial sales are $4000$ per year (meaning $S(0) = 4000$). We can use that information to solve for $e^C$, as $$S(0) =4000 =  e^{C}e^0$$ so clearly $e^C = 4000$. Our final equation is thus $$S(t) = 4000e^{-0.12t}$$ That is all the calculus necessary to solve the problem; I will leave the rest up to you.

Comment: Is the answer 5.78?

Comment: (Assuming I'm right) then yep :) Although I recommend leaving the answer as $$\frac{100\ln(2)}{12}$$ as opposed to rounding

Comment: What I did was this: 2000=4000e^-.12t. I divided by 4000 on both sides and then got this Ln(1/2)=-.12t and then divided by .12. Is this another way of doing the problem to get the answer?

Comment: That is how I did it as well, I just did a bit of additional algebra to make the answer look nicer. Note that $\ln(0.5) = -\ln(2)$ and $-0.12 = -\frac{12}{100}$, so $$\frac{\ln(0.5)}{-0.12} = \frac{-\ln(2)}{\frac{-12}{100}} = \frac{100\ln(2)}{12}$$ Both are exact answers though, which is the important part.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply solve your differential equation.

$$\frac{dS}{dt} = -0.12 S\\S(0) = 4000$$

Has a unique solution $S(t)$. Then, simply solve the equation $$S(t_2) = 2000$$
for $t_2$ to get the halving time.

Comment: So would I divide 2000 by 4000 and then square root it to get my answer?

Comment: @Ben Why square root it? Did you find what $S(t)$ is?

Comment: No, I thought it would be -.12? But that cant be right

Comment: @Ben $S(t)$ is a function. The function that solves the equation $\frac{dS}{dt} = -0.12\cdot S$.